# Merge two different dataframes with loop (python)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm quite new to python and got the following problem.

I have two dataframes, where the first one looks like this:

```
df1
code  product
10-00  apple
10-10  banana
10-20  grape
10-00  cucumber
20-00  tomato
20-10  onion
20-10  garlic
```

and the second one looks like:

```
df2
code  colour
10-00  green
10-10  yellow
10-20  purple
20-00  red
20-10  white
```

I would like to have a loop that would give the following dataframe

```
df
10-00  apple  green
10-10  banana  yellow
10-20  grape  purple
10-00  cucumber  green
20-00  tomato  red
20-10  onion  white
20-10  garlic  white
```

But I really can't figure it out where to start..
Anybody who has experience with such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([pd.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html))

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['code'],how='left')
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'code': ['10-00','10-10'],
    'product': ['apple','banana']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'code': ['10-00','10-10'],
    'colour': ['green','yellow']
})

df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['code'],how='left')

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
    code product  colour
0  10-00   apple   green
1  10-10  banana  yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop, index your `df2` data-frames by the `code` column, the use simple assignment!

```
>>> df1.set_index('code', inplace=True)
>>> df2.set_index('code',inplace=True)
>>> df1
        product
code
10-00     apple
10-10    banana
10-20     grape
10-00  cucumber
20-00    tomato
20-10     onion
20-10    garlic
>>> df2
       colour
code
10-00   green
10-10  yellow
10-20  purple
20-00     red
20-10   white
```

Then simply:

```
>>> df1['colour'] = df2['colour']
>>> df1
        product  colour
code
10-00     apple   green
10-10    banana  yellow
10-20     grape  purple
10-00  cucumber   green
20-00    tomato     red
20-10     onion   white
20-10    garlic   white
```

If you'd rather not index `df1` with code (it would give you a duplicate index) you can always use:

```
>>> df1['colour'] = df2.loc[df1['code']].values
>>> df1
    code   product  colour
0  10-00     apple   green
1  10-10    banana  yellow
2  10-20     grape  purple
3  10-00  cucumber   green
4  20-00    tomato     red
5  20-10     onion   white
6  20-10    garlic   white
```

As long as `df2` is indexed by `'code'`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `set_index` and `join`:

```
df1.set_index('code').join(df2.set_index('code')).reset_index()
```

**Result**

```
    code   product  colour
0  10-00     apple   green
1  10-00  cucumber   green
2  10-10    banana  yellow
3  10-20     grape  purple
4  20-00    tomato     red
5  20-10     onion   white
6  20-10    garlic   white
```

**Explanation**

- `set_index('code')` is applied to both `df1` and `df2` so that we can use it later for joining.
- `join` is applied as a "left join" on index by default.
- `reset_index` is applied to result in order to retrieve a dataframe with the required columns.